# Autorollback for PostgreSQL in case of error in the script

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

We have translated our version of the program to work with PostgreSQL. She previously worked with MSSQL. But we ran into strange behavior in case of an error in PostgreSQL. If an error occurs during the execution of the script, the transaction will go into the interrupted status and wait for a commit or rollback call. In this case, this connection will continue to accept requests, but each call will lead to the error "the current transaction is interrupted, commands are ignored until the end of the transaction block.". All we could find is advice on how to call rollback or commit, but it is not possible to follow this on multiple servers. We will naturally fix the error that led to the crash, but later. This issue leads to severe server side crashes. Isn't it logical to rollback automatically? Couldn't execute the script, rollback and continue working. Here's what I think is logical. Please convince me if I am wrong.

We are using NpgSql to work with PostgreSQL, maybe he can help us with our problem? Perhaps there is some way to close the problematic connection or stop using it before committing the transaction?

We are using PostgreSQL 9.5 version. Our application is written in ASP.NET.

UPD, after an error in the script, the process [62493] generates many errors of this kind:

```
14:05:58.827 [62493] ERROR:     DISCARD ALL cannot be executed inside a transaction block
14:05:58.827 [62493] OPERATOR:  DISCARD ALL
14:05:58.827 [62493] ERROR:     current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
14:05:58.827 [62493] OPERATOR:  BEGIN
14:05:58.827 [62493] ERROR:     current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
14:05:58.827 [62493] OPERATOR:  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
14:05:58.827 [62493] ERROR:     current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

*Among these calls are calls to real stored procedures from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Let me convince you. Observe this transaction:

```
/* poor man's table reorganization */
BEGIN;
CREATTE TABLE reorganized (LIKE mydata);  -- syntax error
INSERT INTO reorganized SELECT * FROM mydata;
DROP TABLE mydata;
ALTER TABLE reorganized RENAME TO mydata;
COMMIT;
```

If an error would automatically cause a rollback, or if the statement with the error were rolled back, but the transaction could continue, the above transaction would lose the data in `mydata`.

Moreover, such a behavior would violate the atomicity guarantee of a transaction: either *all* statements succeed or *no* statement succeeds.

To work around this, you can use standard SQL savepoints:

```
BEGIN;
/* do some work */
SAVEPOINT a;
/* perform a statement that might fail */
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT a; -- only if the statement above fails
/* continue doing work */
COMMIT;
```

But don't use more than 64 savepoints per transaction if you want good performance.

Comment: Laurerenz Albe, I don't need to continue executing this script, I just need to log the error. After this error, this connection continues to accept execution requests as part of the connection pool. At the same time, issue an error about an interrupted transaction. Sorry, maybe I misinterpreted the problem in the description.

Comment: From your log it looks like you are returning a connection to the connection pool *before* committing or rolling back the transaction. That won't work. Perhaps you could change the "cleanup query" for your connection pool to `ROLLBACK; DISCARD ALL;`, but the proper fix is to fix your code.