# Postgresql Transaction Block

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I am trying to understand how to run a transaction in PostgreSQL. Here is a sample script:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    value INT CHECK(value>=0),
    data VARCHAR(255)
);

START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO test(id,value,data) VALUES (1,1,'apple');
    INSERT INTO test(id,value,data) VALUES (2,2,'banana');
    INSERT INTO test(id,value,data) VALUES (3,-1,'augh!');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM test;
```

Of course, there is an error on the 3rd `INSERT` and it stops.

When I highlight the block from `START` to `SELECT` statement and run I get an error. If I then try to run the `SELECT` statement I get:

> ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block.

I understand that, and if I run the `COMMIT` separately, I can proceed. I find that the transaction has been rolled back, and that there are no rows in the table, as I would expect.

Is there a way of doing this without having to run the `COMMIT` separately? In Microsoft SQL (yes, I know, it’s not the same), if I `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, it behaves just that way: I can highlight the block, run it, and, if there’s an error the transaction is either committed or rolled back.

Comment: What do you mean by "*running the `COMMIT` separately"*? You need to issue a `rollback;` to exit the aborted transaction, abandoning the snapshot/context that's no longer valid. Your third insert fails, but your commit and select also fail because you're still in a context that doesn't see a reliable view of the database state it could interact with.

Comment: @Zegarek I know I can commit or  rollback. The point is if I run the commit line it finishes off the transaction, and I can then run the select statement and see that nothing was committed. In MSSQL that transaction would have been finished off without running a commit or rollback separately.

Comment: Got it. I expected everything after the error to just keep throwing errors, except an actual `rollback` - turns out `commit` automatically becomes a `rollback` here. [Auto-commit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.20.8.5.2.9.1.1.2) and auto-rollback are both client-side features in PostgreSQL. There's an [auto-rollback option in pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.1/query_tool_toolbar.html#query-execution). I don't think you can force this behaviour through as a db-side setting, like in MS. [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67885387/5298879)

Comment: What client are you using to run this in?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I’ve tried it in PGAdmin as well as SQL Pro on the Macintosh

Comment: Alright some digging found that `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is an attribute of the  `T-SQL` procedural language. If you want to emulate that the you will need to use a Postgres PL, say [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) in particular [Trapping Errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Does that mean I need to put this in a `DO` block?

Comment: At the minimum, though a `DO` cannot take arguments or return anything.  Otherwise a function(args & return) or procedure(args).

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. I’ve added this in the form of an answer. I can’t see how you would do this before version 11, though, since I can only make this work in a `DO` block or in a procedure. I can’t make it work in a function.

Comment: Good that you found a solution, but you must be using an unusual client program: If you run your five statements all at once, the transaction should roll back as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from @AdrianKlaver, I have a solution using an anonynmous code block.

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test(id,value,data) VALUES (1,1,'apple');
    INSERT INTO test(id,value,data) VALUES (2,2,'banana');
    INSERT INTO test(id,value,data) VALUES (3,-1,'augh!');  --  error
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN ROLLBACK;
END $$;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Since the block will commit if successful, this behaves as I would have expected.

If you use a procedure, you can feed it some parameters and make the process more useful.

Prior to version 11, there was no anonymous code block or procedure syntax, and I haven’t been able to make this work for a function.